# SQLite, PDO, and PHP: New inserts not being saved

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have a few PHP (version 5.1.6) scripts and an sqlite3 database. For a while, everything was working fine, including inserts, updates, selects, and deletes.

Now:

- Select statements still work fine
- Inserts, deletes, and updates all fail without an error that I can see. A `-journal` file is created in the same directory as the database, but it later disappears. The sqlite file remains unmodified.

I can't really figure out what, if anything, has changed. Permissions are the same. I've been able to open and save the database in another program, and replaced it with that version, but I still have the same problem. The scripts originally were all in autocommit mode; using explicit commits does not fix the problem either.

If I replace the database file with an older backup, everything works just fine.

I'd appreciate any ideas for troubleshooting. Thank you!

Comment: How do you know that your inserts, deletes and updates fail? Can you run the sqlite3 shell and see what happens? Do you trigger before inserts, deletes or updates?

Comment: I'd say the _file_ permissions on your sqlite database are most likely the problem. Can the webserver/PHP user _write_ to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the permissions. Make sure PHP/Apache has read/write capability and owns the folder and the SQLite database file.

Comment: Thanks - yes, the permissions are still the same, with both read and write access.